# Modifying web api 2 odata get query result

Tags: entity-framework, odata, webapp2

I have an Odata controller get method like bellow:

```
 public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [MyEnableQuery(PageSize = 48, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.OrderBy | AllowedQueryOptions.Top | AllowedQueryOptions.Skip | AllowedQueryOptions.InlineCount | AllowedQueryOptions.Filter, AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.SubstringOf | AllowedFunctions.ToLower)]

    public IQueryable<tbDefine_Products> GetProducts([FromODataUri] int CategoryID)
    {
        ProductHandler _handler = new ProductHandler();
        IQueryable<tbDefine_Products> _list =_handler.GetProductActiveList(CategoryID);
        return _list;
    }  
}
```

Now i wants to modify my query result before sending it to clinet... i want to something like _list.Tolist() and then iterating through the result array

```
       List<tbDefine_Products> _list2 = _list.ToList<tbDefine_Products>();
       for (int i = 0; i < _list2.Count; i++)
       {
        / *some code here to modify result */
       }
```

I have read a little about ActionFilterAttribute and  ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted and 
    HttpActionExecutedContext Classes but i dont know how implement my ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have already have a implementation about EnableQuery Attribute : `MyEnableQuery`, you should override the method:

```
public virtual IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
```

get the query result first and then filter the result:

```
var result = base.ApplyQuery(queryable, queryOptions);
// filter the result.
return result;
```